# Need to design a SQL Server pair where one is read-only while the other is updated by a batch process

Tags: sql-server, azure

This would seem to me a common scenario, but I don't know what the current terminology and solution would be.

We have database tables that are updated nightly by a batch process.

At the same time, we require 24/7 read access to the data.

My thought is to have a set exposed to the batch process, and when that finishes it gets switched on for read access.

Likewise, the DB that had been available for read is swapped back and is the target for the batch process. (Note, these DB's are in Azure)

Make sense?

Is this a likely way to deal with this scenario?

What do we call this technique?

Comment: Sounds like a great job for replication to me.

Comment: Yes this is called a read only replica. This is often implemented using "availability groups" but I believe this might be Enterprise Edition only (pricey) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/active-secondaries-readable-secondary-replicas-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: ...although in my experience, batch loads in the source can case a problem with transactional replication because they lock up the transaction log (until it is replicated out to the secondary) and end up blowing out disk space.

Comment: Better  detail and options here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53105/creating-a-read-only-replica-of-sql-server-database-for-reports

Comment: Thanks for the feedback,  I'll look into replication, but I am trying to recall another  design where tables could swap names instantly.  Thus we would updating set A and reading from set B, and then when the batch finished we would swap and start updating set B.  Connection strings would not have to change.  There are some restrictions about the physical location of the tables.  Ring any bells?

Comment: You're probably thinking about the switch partition trick which is marginally better than renaming tables. https://sqlsunday.com/2014/08/24/reloading-fact-tables-with-zero-downtime/ But it takes extra coding and if the target table is not identical (indexes, data types) it fails. A simpler (though more intensive) solution is to use snapshot isolation. While you are loading data (inside a transaction), readers can still see a version of the data from before you started the transaction.

Comment: Yes!  The switch partition is the one I had heard of but couldn't track down again